# Where does this question belong?

Tags: discussion

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/which-version-of-tilp-should-i-use

The linked question does not belong in Software Recs, so where does it belong on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

If a question does not belong on a given "stack", this does not necessarily mean there *is* some other stack it fits. There are indeed questions fitting on *no* SE site: e.g. because they cannot fit the model (SE sites are no discussion forums), or there simply is no specific stack having the topic on its scope.

The question in question (oops) is not about recommending a software for a given task, which is why it doesn't fit here. It's rather asking which version to use in conjunction with a specific OS version. I don't know what speaks against the "latest version", but I'm not home in that area: sometimes there are in fact good reasons why one might prefer to stick to an "older" version. Now, whether it fits on a different SE site (and if so, which), depends on the focus:

- if you're concerned about compatibility issues with the OS version you're using, check for a site specific to your OS (I thought we had some Apple/MacOS specific site? Or must I [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)?)
- if it's for some specific feature set, maybe there's an SE site specific to the field (like [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) for web applications)
- … (cannot think of other elements right now – but see the [listing of SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites))

Whatever might *sound* fitting, make sure to check first with their help center. You always find the corresponding on-topic description at the URL `<SE-Site-Main-URL>/help/on-topic` (e.g. `http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic` for SoftwareRecs).

If you checked everything, and didn't find anything, chances are you found above described "gap" for which no SE site exists.